# Output name from a MemberShipUser

Tags: .net, umbraco, umbraco7

Basically what I'm trying to do is make a table of all employees with their names as well. But I can't seem to find a proper way to get the name from the user, I can only get the UserName and Email.

I am looking for something that does something similair to this: `@Members.GetCurrentMemberProfileModel()` but then it has to fetch the ProfileModel based on the username (or something like that). I've been looking for quite some time but can't find it.

```
@{
    var headQuartersEmployees = (List<MembershipUser>) ViewBag.HeadQuartersEmployees;
}

@foreach (var employee in headQuartersEmployees)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@employee.Name <-- ??? Name is not available here ???</td>
        <td>@employee.LastLoginDate</td>
        <td>@employee.UserName</td>
        <td>@employee.Email</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a class="btn btn-rabo-transparant" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-rabo-transparant remove-btn" href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after a few hours I found out that I could use this to fix my issue..

```
@ApplicationContext.Services.MemberService.GetByUsername(employee.UserName).Name
```

It's kinda nasty because now I need to query the db again just to get a name, while the object already has the `Member` object in it, but it's inaccessible because the property is private...